# Chef Attribute set a variable in an array hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, variables, hash, chef-infra

In a cookbook I have the following in my attributes/default.rb:

```
default.ark.packages = [ 
  {
    'name' => 'optipng',
    'url' => 'http://squirrelyjim.cloudfront.net/heroes/optipng-0.7.5.tar.gz', 
    'version' => '0.7.5'
  },
  {
    'name' => 'imagemagick',
    'url' => 'http://squirrelyjim.cloudfront.net/heroes/ImageMagick-6.9.0-4.tar.gz',
    'version' => '6.9.0-4'
  },
  {
    'name' => 'jpegoptim',
    'url' => 'http://squirrelyjim.cloudfront.net/heroes/jpegoptim-1.4.1.tar.gz',
    'version' => '1.4.1'
  }
]
```

I then call those values using the ark resource as follows:

```
node.ark.packages.each do |pkg|  
  ark pkg['name'] do
    url pkg['url']
    version pkg['version']
    action :install_with_make
    notifies :run, "execute[ldconfig]", :immediately
  end
end
```

This works great but I would like to somehow get the version to automatically get called at the end of the url, instead of typing it out twice.  Is there a way to get a value in a hash updated with another value from the same hash, similar to:

```
http://squirrelyjim.cloudfront.net/heroes/optipng-#{version}.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically build the URL inside the loop:

```
node.ark.packages.each do |pkg|  
  url = "http://squirrelyjim.cloudfront.net/heroes/#{pkg['name']}-#{pkg['version']}.tar.gz"

  ark pkg['name'] do
    url url
    version pkg['version']
    action :install_with_make
    notifies :run, "execute[ldconfig]", :immediately
  end
end
```